# Eclipse double click unreliable in Package Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, double-click

Double clicking on a `.java` file only registers some of the time in the Package Explorer of Eclipse, in the editor it always works. How can I get Eclipse to always register double clicks?

I use Eclipse 4.5.1 on GNOME Shell 3.18.3 on Arch Linux 4.4.1-2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in eclipse that is connected to gtk3:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=473093

It seems this error is present only on Dark Theme
The above link proposes the following fix:

1. go to your eclipse installation directory
2. open org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.1.200.v20160815-0536/css/e4-dark.css
3. around line 139 change the following code:

   ```
   .MPartStack.active Tree,
   .MPartStack.active CTabFolder Canvas {
      background-color: #262626;
      color: #CCC;
   }
   ```

   to the following:

   ```
   .MPartStack.active CTabFolder Canvas {
      background-color: #262626;
      color: #CCC;
   }
   ```
4. restart eclipse

Comment: Oh and if you installed eclipse using oomph the plugin will be located in
~/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.1.200.v20160815-0536/css/e4-dark.css

Comment: I use the Dark Theme indeed and the described change (deleting one line) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

it can be controlled through

Windows->Preferences->General->Open Mode

Check the details here
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftopenmode.htm

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Saurav

Comment: This is not my problem. It is already in double click mode, where a single click selects and a double click opens in an editor. The problem is that it is *unreliable*, i.e. sometimes a double click opens the editor and sometimes it does not.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but I've found out that this happens only when switching focus from the editor to the package view; my workaround is to click once, wait for the editor to focus, then double click, in which case it does work. And this issue persists in Neon, which make me think it's an GTK/SWT mismatch issue.